# When debugging my code a variable doesn't appear its value correctly in debug window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have a strange problem When debugging my code (just one line of code) a variable doesn't appear its value correctly in the debug window.
Note that that problem just occurs in a specific project but the other projects don't occur.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    wstring u16 = L"Hello 日本語 سلام Ä भारतीय עברית ไทย"; 
    return 0;
}
```

The following are two screenshots of two different projects:

[image]

---

[image]

I am using "MS VS2019".
There are no problems in the IDE but that problem happened suddenly and I don't know what caused it.

**Is there any solution?**

Comment: Note: There's no *guarantee* that the debug symbols in your executable (and as interpreted by your debugger), will be accurate/correct. You may, at *any time* be debugging an executable where the debug symbols are missing, actively wrong or what you expect. You just have to deal with that.  At *best*, debug symbols (and your debugger) *try* to help you, but they sometimes fail and you have to deal with the fallout. This is especially relevant when debugging optimized code.

Comment: Problem with the text editor, it saved the file in an encoding that the compiler did not expect.  Use utf8 with a BOM, File > Save As, click the arrow on the Save button.

Comment: Can you *print* the value to the standard output? Is the output correct?

Comment: In addition to the other comments, the variable `u16` is never used, so the compiler is free to leave it out entirely, especially in an optimized build.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you. Previously, the file was saved as `Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) Codepage 65001`.  But when changing to `Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) Codepage 65001` the problem solved. The problem was in the signature of UTF-8.

Comment: @LionKing You can use the [`/source-charset:utf-8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/source-charset-set-source-character-set?view=vs-2019) switch for UTF-8 source files without a BOM.

Comment: I thank everyone who tried to help me. The problem was in the file encoding (the signature of UTF-8).